# Like button error - but not all pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a Like button on my theatre pages. For example:

http://raleighlittletheatre.org/shows/11-12/crucible.html

Strangely many of them say the starter message (even though I know people that have Liked this page):

> Be the first of your friends to recommend this.

When I click the Like button it reports an error "Error" and when I click it I get:

> There was an error liking the page. If you are the page owner, please try running your page through the linter on the Facebook devsite and fixing any errors.

I ran the linter, but there are no errors other than a warning that my image is too small.

A couple of other pages also have this error, although I'm sure they didn't use to. However this page does not have the error and I am using the same code on them (all via a CMS):

http://raleighlittletheatre.org/shows/11-12/firecracker.html

Clearly I created an error that affects some pages, but not others. Ideas?

Even stranger, if I log off Facebook then I see that 93 or 27 or some non-zero number of people (at least some of which I'm friends with, I'm certain) like these pages.